# Multiply images boxes

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a simple form with 10 picture boxes like: `pictureBox1`, `pictureBox2`, `pictureBox3`...

And I have a folder with 10 images like:  `image1`, `image2`, `image3`...

Now I am smart enough to know that I don't want to hard code `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = image1`, `pictureBox2.ImageLocation = image2`...  Rather, I need to create some kind of loop or array that will populate my picture boxes with their respective images, but I am not smart enough to figure out how.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    pictureBox[i].ImageLocation = image[i];
}
```

Eventually, I was hoping this project would scale dynamically, if I have a file with say 12 images, the program will simply create 12 picture boxes and load the images.  A little help would be great.

Comment: A little hard to help you with that info. How do you know how many picture boxes you will handle? I think this is the first step. So you can limit your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there would roughty work though I would suggest a list.

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

//code to populate your lists

for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    pictureBoxes[i].Image = images[i];
}
```

If you want to make sure you have enough images for your `PictureBox` list you could check ahead of time:

```
if (images.Count >= pictureBoxes.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Count; i++)
    {
        pictureBoxes[i].Image = images[i];
    }
}
```

...or fill out as many as you can before running out of images.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Count && i < images.Count; i++)
{
    pictureBoxes[i].Image = images[i];
}
```

---

EDIT:
So if you want to use strings to set the location of the images instead you can do that.  Check this out:

```
  List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
  List<string> imageLocations = new List<string>();

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     PictureBox PB1 = new PictureBox();
     PB1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
     PB1.Size = new Size(144, 197);
     Controls.Add(PB1);
     PictureBox PB2 = new PictureBox();
     PB2.Location = new Point(145, 0);
     PB2.Size = new Size(327, 250);
     Controls.Add(PB2);

     pictureBoxes.Add(PB1);
     pictureBoxes.Add(PB2);

     imageLocations.Add(@"C:\PicExample\image1.jpg");
     imageLocations.Add(@"C:\PicExample\image2.jpg");

     for (int i = 0; i < pictureBoxes.Count && i < imageLocations.Count; i++)
     {
        pictureBoxes[i].ImageLocation = imageLocations[i];
     }
  }
```

[image: PICTURES!]

---

EDIT for Iteratively Creating `PictureBoxe` List:

If you want to not have to worry about hard-coding your list (and your picture boxes will be the same size) you could do something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < HoweverManyPictureBoxesYouWant; i++)
 {
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
    PB.Name = "PB" + i.ToString();
    PB.Location = new Point(250 * i, 0); //Edit this as you see fit for location, i'm just putting them in a row
    PB.Size = new Size(250, 250);
    PB.ImageLocation = @"C:\PicExample\image" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
    Controls.Add(PB);
    pictureBoxes.Add(PB); //You only need to do this if you want the PB's in a list for other reasons than setting the image location
 }
```

Comment: Ahhh!  I am starting to get the "picture".  How can I point the list towards the image files location or is it just defaulting to the project "debug" folder?  Thanks

Comment: Is the PictureBox PB1 = new PictureBox(); dynamically adding picture boxes instead of me having to put them on the form prior to executing the code?

Comment: That works perfect.  How can I make PictureBox PB1, PB2, PBxx more flexible so I don't need to hard code a PictureBox PBxx for every picture box?  There my be 20 picture boxes on the form.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  This is an excellent example and I hope others can learn from what you did here.  I just wish I had enough 'reps' to vote your answer up.

Comment: No problem.  =)  Enjoy Stack Overflow!!